# Is it possible to retroactively create associations between models?

Tags: cakephp

As the title says, I'm trying to bake my models but since I haven't baked all of my models yet I can't establish associations with tables I haven't baked yet, so I'd like to skip it all until I've baked the models, then run through them again later to add all the associations.

Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want a shell that updates your existing, already baked code, models, with additional associations later?

Technically that's possible but not a core feature. You'll have to write such a shell yourself.

But I don't see a problem adding them manually later, it's a 5 minute task.

Comment: If that's the case I can see why they didn't implement it, thanks :)

Comment: An association is just an array. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html Would you mind to flag the answer as correct then? Thanks.